# "Error while waiting for device: adb connection not available, or was terminated"?

Tags: java, android

In MY Android Studio 2.1.1

I have encounter following problem :

[image]

I have restarted the ADB and I also made a new emulator. Why do I keep getting this error? I have also restarted the emulator and Android Studio.

Comment: Have you tried killing adb and restarting it?

Comment: I've restarted the adb, that wasn't the fix.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I clicked on `Run->Debug 'app'`.

This worked for me.

It occurs sometimes and reconnecting the device may not help. So just let Android Studio itself debug may help.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Such a short answer would normally be left as a comment, because it is not complete. (You'll get the right to comment once you've given a few solid answers, that others find useful) (Suggestion: Can you tell us *why* this fixes the problem?)

Having said that, if your answer is later up-voted or accepted, then someone *did* find it useful. ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It's the first time I answered in Stack Overflow, so ...
It happens to work and hoping that it may help others with the same problem. I would complete it once I figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

I had some problem , it's easy : enter to:  Task Manager > search for All process "adb.exe" put End Task for adb.exe ! And retry RUN ! This work for me.

Comment: This did it for me! On Mac it is Activity Monitor (instead of Task Manager), but works the same here.

Answer (score 1):

On mac, open Activity Monitor -> Search for "adb" -> click the process -> Quit. Then try again.